# trying to calculate the distance between 2 3dimentional coordinates in java

Tags: java, string, coordinates

so i am trying to make a program that can return the distance between 2 coordinates.

but i get the coordinates in a string format like this: 23 60 600.

23 is the X axis 60 is the Y axis and 600 is the Z.

to calculate the difference between those coordinates i use this formula:

Distance = `√[ (xA − xB)2 + (yA − yB)2 + (zA − zB)2 ]`

Note that the coordinates can be negative

so at the end i am trying to do this

```
(input) coordinate a: 20 10 500

(input) coordinate b: -20 200 21

(output) distance between a and b
```

this is what i have tried but after a while i came to the conclusion that it will not work.

```
String[] parts1 = cord1.split(" ");
String[] parts2 = cord2.split(" ");

//  space    x    y    z
//   [0]    [1]  [2]  [3]

int v1 = Integer.parseInt(parts1[1]) - Integer.parseInt(parts2[1]) * 2;
int v2 = Integer.parseInt(parts1[2]) - Integer.parseInt(parts2[2]) * 2;
int v3 = Integer.parseInt(parts1[3]) - Integer.parseInt(parts2[3]) * 2;

double conversion = v1 + v2 + v3;
String a = String.valueOf(conversion);
String b = a.replace("-","");
double c = Integer.parseInt(b);
System.out.println(c);
double dist = Math.sqrt(c);
```

it gave this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3
at codes.Main.main(Main.java:36)
```

(line 36 is:   double c = Integer.parseInt(b);)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several things wrong with this code. Most importantly:

```
int v1 = Integer.parseInt(parts1[1]) - Integer.parseInt(parts2[1]) * 2;
int v2 = Integer.parseInt(parts1[2]) - Integer.parseInt(parts2[2]) * 2;
int v3 = Integer.parseInt(parts1[3]) - Integer.parseInt(parts2[3]) * 2;
```

This doesn't do `(xA - xB)^2` etc. which is what you need. This simply doubles the coordinates of `B`. Instead you should have:

```
int v1 = Math.pow(Integer.parseInt(parts1[1]) - Integer.parseInt(parts2[1]), 2);
// same for v2 and v3
```

And the square of a real number is always non-negative, so you don't need to remove any minus signs.

```
double dist = Math.sqrt(v1 + v2 + v3);
```

Comment: thnx this was the answer i was looking for :D